# How can I get a list of all my paid (only) apps in the Play Store?

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I'm interested to know all of my apps that I paid for in the Google Play Store. Is there an easy way to retrieve this list filtering only paid applications?

Comment: On the Play Store website or the app (or both)?

Comment: If you use Google Wallet only for Play Store, you can list them up after login to `wallet.google.com`.

Comment: See also [How to see all the purchased apps in google play store](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/148165/how-to-see-all-the-purchased-apps-in-google-play-store) , particularly https://play.google.com/store/account?purchaseFilter=apps

Answer (score 10):

(1) Check out [Legacy Play Store](http://phandroid.com/2012/07/20/legacy-play-store-brings-back-previously-paid-apps-list-download/). You can get the list on UNINSTALLED PAID apps. INSTALLED list includes both PAID and UNPAID.

If you decide to install it, you may need to:

- use Root Explorer (I had troubles with Astro and File Expert)
- copy the apk to /system/app
- chmod the apk to 644

NOTE: It works on my Samsung Galaxy S2, running CyanogenMod9.

EDIT: Hmm. Website is currently unavailable. Post a comment if you can't access it. I could probably upload the apk somewhere. [Or you could search for the app elsewhere]

(2) AndroidPolice just featured a [GreaseMonkey script](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/13/this-greasemonkey-script-lets-you-see-all-my-apps-on-one-page-and-filters-between-freepaid-in-the-web-market/) that allows you to separate your paid apps in Google Play. You might also want to check it out.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this list on browser then you can go for the Greasemonkey Artem script which can show your paid and free apps in different lists.

Check out full detail and installation guide here [Greasemonkey Artem script](http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/10/13/this-greasemonkey-script-lets-you-see-all-my-apps-on-one-page-and-filters-between-freepaid-in-the-web-market/)

Answer (score 4):

Right now, you can do the following:

1. Open the play store app.
2. Open the options by swiping in from the left of the screen.
3. Select my account", then scroll down to see your order history.
4. Tap " more" and you'll see a list of everything you've paid for on the play store.
5. Success!

This worked as of November 2015 with Android 6.0. I'm sure Google will change it soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

Another method (if you only use Google wallet for Google play purchases) is to simply look at your Google wallet purchase history. If you only use it for Google play app purchases, they will all be listed here.

To keep things organised in the future, if you wish, you could always create a folder on your home screen containing all your paid apps and drop in any additions as you go.