# List of purchased apps and app install/uninstall history log anywhere?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, logging, paid-apps, history

My device was damaged and since then I've had to order a hardware replacement.
Given that all purchases and application installs/uninstalls via Google Play Store
are carried out in connection with my Google account, I would like to know whether
there is a way to:

1. How can I view a list of apps I purchased, perhaps arranged in reverse chronological
   order according to purchase date? The [Google Play Apps](https://play.google.com/apps) site displays all applications I've ever installed, including free ones. WHen I go to `My apps` on the Android Google Play Store applications, I don't see the apps I paid for which were on my old device (same Google account).
2. Is there an application with a graphical user interface which displays all the
   history of installed/uninstalled applications linked to my Google account?
   [This thread](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/83030/history-of-installed-uninstalled-apps) seems to suggest that this is possible via the DOS command-prompt on Windows using the `adb` (Android Debug Bridge) tool, or even on Android with `BusyBox`. But I am looking for a GUI application, possibly one that uses info stored on the Google account in the cloud rather than in a log file on the device.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The first half of your question is answered by [How can I get a list of all my paid (only) apps in the Play Store?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/30519/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-my-paid-only-apps-in-the-play-store)

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that when I go to `Google Play -> Apps menu -> My Apps menu item` I get two filters called `INSTALLED` and `ALL`. When I click on `ALL` I can see not only the applications on my phone but also those applications which were on my old phone which were installed using the same account, including both free and purchased apps, but if any of such paid apps are deleted from this Google Play ALL list then I have to use the [My Paid Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jkg.mypaidapps) application to find them again.

Comment: I didn't purchase my applications using Google Wallet, but used money from phone top-ups instead. Too bad the [My Paid Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jkg.mypaidapps) application has to be installed to retrieve all purchased apps in a single list and this behavior is not available in the Google Play Store mobile application.

Comment: I've also looked for the second part, but its nowhere to be found. I'm afraid google just doesn't want such a feature. You can find your google play store search history, but not the install history.

Comment: See [How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204752/3573) for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

To view a list of apps purchased in the play store click on the menu icon then account. Under account you will see order history.

Comment: That only covers a part of the question and already answered on this site ([List of purchased apps and app install/uninstall history log anywhere?](//android.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/112723)). OP is also asking for install/uninstall history log. Consider adding answer to the missing portion. If you cannot you may like to delete the answer as it does not help and instead may invite down votes

Comment: No . OP is asking for purchased apps

Comment: The OP is asking for both, its in the Title.