# How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, 8.0-oreo

I need to generate a text export of the list under the MyApps-> Library Tab of the Play Store App for Android. I need a list of every App that I have ever installed from the Play Store, and not just a list of the subset of those which are currently installed. Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) to export out of Google services a list of all activity involving the **Google Play Store** for a Google account.

No root or even device is required as you are exporting out of Google's collected cloud data, you just need account credentials.

For reference I just did it for my account and was able to obtain a zip file containing the following JSON files:

```
Devices.json
Installs.json
Library.json
Order History.json
Play Settings.json
Purchase History.json
Redemption History.json
Reviews.json
```

If you check `Installs.json` you should be able to extract out the name of the app from "title" as well as when it was first installed/last updated.

A few caveats that I see:

1. Apps on pre-Google Play devices appear to show up with package app name (i.e. com.publisher.awesomeapp). The earliest in my history is 2011. So there appears to be Android Market installs are held in this dataset.
2. `Devices.json` only seems to hold recently accessed devices. I'm pretty sure I had older devices with Google Play but they aren't listed. Its possible those old devices (Gingerbread/KitKat) have 'aged' out due to lack of access so that might explain why the older app installs like from 2011 show `"deviceDisplayName": "Unknown Device"`
3. `title` could either be plain app name or package name.

As the files are in text in JSON format, it shouldn't be too difficult extract out what you need.

From @JimCramer's comments, one can use https://json-csv.com/ to get a `csv` file from a `json` file.

1. Download Google Takeout `zip` file.
2. Unpack `zip` file
3. Upload `Library.json` file to that service
4. Review "Choose Output Options", if required
5. Click "Convert JSON to CSV"
6. For the `Library.json` file there will be three columns:

   > 'DocumentType', 'Title', 'Acquisition Time'
7. Download CSV result file
8. Import into spreadsheet, sort by 'DocumentType' to get `Android Apps` and enjoy

From what I recall, Excel itself can import `json` files.

If you don't want a third-party site to have access to your data. A search in your favorite search engine naming your spreadsheet tool with the topic of 'JSON conversion' will show either how to do it or what plugins/scripts are required for the effect.

Comment: @Morrison Chang - I wanted to let you know that  your Anser/Procedure worked, and to thank you very much for replying to my question because it saved me a lot of time and gave me exactly what I wanted. I am grateful.  The ZIP Takeout File from the Google Play Service downloaded to my device. . I unpacked it and found the file Library.json.  I then uploaded that file to the free Json to CVS file conversion utility on the web page https://json-csv.com/ which eaily converted my file to .csv and .xlsx format, and downloded that back to my local storge.