# How do I identify on when was an application installed previously. Currently I don’t have the app on my android device

Tags: android-device-manager

I did explore all the articles and video. But that did not help either. Ideally I want to identify the last time an app was installed on my android device .which is currently not available .

In other words , is there a way to identify installed date of an app in android.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout). I'm unsure whether it lists sideloaded and system apps as well. Download the Google Play Store data only. Extract the data from the archive and look for your app in the files *Install.json* and *Library.json* under Google Play Store directory. Those two files can be opened in a text editor, such as Notepad++, Sublime Text Editor, etc.

Related:

- [Where can I find out when I installed an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/25263/96277)
- [How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204752/96277)