# Find out a list of all previously installed packages

Tags: adb, data-recovery

I'd like to know if it's possible to find out what packages were installed on an Android device using ADB, for when the simple "My Apps" library in Google Play doesn't list everything I'm looking for.

If possible, a generic answer would be appreciated for future reference. In this specific case I'm looking to figure out which asset flip mobile game (out of thousands of similar clones) was accidentally deleted on an Android 8.1 phone.

Comment: If installed from Play Store see: [How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204752/3573)

Answer (score -1):

Use pm. pm command is a package manager which allows you to list, install, uninstal and disable your device packages.

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

should do the job.

Comment: Hello. OP wants to know about a package that is no longer installed in the system. PM commands don't give that information.

Comment: Then I have no idea is that even possible. System app apks are stored somewhere in /system even when you uninstall them from system, same with stock apps.  When you uninstall third party app by pm you can use -k switch and all data and cache of app won't be deleted. But as I said Android doesn't have any kind of "app history".