# Installation date of deleted Apps

Tags: applications, date-and-time

I need to view the Installation Date from an App on an Android Phone. Is there any way to view the Installation Date. Is there an log file in the file Manager form Android or an way to view the Installation Date in the Settings or in the Play Store. Even if the App is already deleted?

Thank you for responses

Comment: The first time an app is installed this is usually recorded as "purchase" even for free apps. Thus you may be able to find the app in the Play Store "Budget & history" including the date of the purchase.

Comment: Thank you for posting the the correct location. If there are no in-app/simple answers, see: [How to export a list as Text of all Play Store Apps that I have ever installed](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204752/3573) for a possible solution.