# How to see all the purchased apps in google play store

Tags: google-play-store, paid-apps

I have purchased several apps on Google Play Store. I've installed a new ROM, and I want to reinstall the purchased apps. Is there any way to see only purchased apps in play store.

I know that there is a way to see all the previously installed apps, but is there any filter to list only the purchased apps?

Answer (score 16):

Go to  *Playstore menu → Account → Order history*,  you will find all details of purchases made using the linked  account. Click on the apps you wish to install from there and you are done

**Edit:** Added additional pics to depict the process, seeing that there are answers saying it cannot be done (App chosen is purchased but currently not installed)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Using the web you can filter for just apps https://play.google.com/store/account?purchaseFilter=apps

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but not with the Play Store app, but check out the apps called [My Paid Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jkg.mypaidapps) or [Purchased Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azefsw.purchasedapps) and there may be others but I am unaware of them, either should be exactly what you are looking for.

As another user posted it can be done via the web page, but not the app on the device.

Comment: @beeshyams No, your method shows all purchases including music, books, movies, in-game purchases, etc., not all purchased apps **only** which my method will allow you to since the apps I listed have the ability to sort and filter all purchases.

Comment: @acejavelin- Thanks for the clarification- I have never purchased anything else (apart from apps), so it didn't occur to me +1

Comment: @beeshyams Trust me, they are there, I have purchased around 40 apps over the years, and hundreds of songs, even free music shows up in your order history, books, etc. :)

Answer (score 4):

Using the account page on the web you can filter for just apps from all purchases. 
https://play.google.com/store/account?purchaseFilter=apps. On an android device open the link with a browser instead of the Play Store. The Play Store app cannot filter apps from other purchases.

From the web you can also install apps on any devices connected with your account.